# IntegrityError at /update_dept/1/ NOT NULL constraint failed: main_department.dept_name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a simple django models of doctors and department. there is not link between them and when I try to update the department then it is show me this error `IntegrityError at /update_dept/1/ NOT NULL constraint failed: main_department.dept_name` this error is new for me. I check other similar question also but didn't get much. so pls help me.

here is my view.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Doctorslist,Departmentform
from .models import Department, Doctor
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import (CreateView, DetailView, UpdateView, ListView, TemplateView, DeleteView) 
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
import os
# Create your views here.


def add_show(request):
    form = Doctorslist()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Doctorslist(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = Doctorslist()
    stud = Doctor.objects.all
    context = {'form':form,
                'stu':stud
                }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)


def update_data(request, id):
    prod = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        prod.doc_image = request.FILES['doc_image']
        prod.kycdocument = request.FILES['kycdocument']
        prod.name = request.POST.get('name')
        prod.phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        prod.email = request.POST.get('email')
        prod.city = request.POST.get('city')
        prod.speciality = request.POST.get('email')
        prod.save()
        messages.success(request, "Product Updated Successfully")
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'prod':prod}
    return render(request, 'main/update_doc.html', context)

def delete_data(request,id):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pi = Doctor.objects.get(pk = id)
        pi.delete()
        return redirect('/')

def add_show_dept(request):
    form = Departmentform()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Departmentform(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = Departmentform()
    dept = Department.objects.all
    context = {'form':form,
                'stu':dept
                }
    return render(request, 'main/pages-profile.html', context)


def update_dept_data(request, id):
    prod = Department.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        prod.dept_name = request.POST.get('dept_name')
        prod.dept_Email = request.POST.get('dept_Email')
        prod.save()
        messages.success(request, "Product Updated Successfully")
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'prod':prod}
    return render(request, 'main/update_dept.html', context)
```

here is model.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
import os 
# Create your models here.
import datetime
def get_file_path(request, filename):
    filename_original = filename
    nowTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
    filename = "%s%s" % (nowTime, filename_original)
    return os.path.join('uploads/', filename)


class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    speciality =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    doc_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path)
    kycdocument = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path, null = True, blank = True)


class Department(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dept_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    dept_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

here is forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from .models import Doctor,Department


class Doctorslist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name','phone_number','email', 'city', 'speciality', 'doc_image', 'kycdocument')
        # widgets = {
        #     'name':  forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
        #     'email':  forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        #     'city':  forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        #     'speciality': forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        # }   


class Departmentform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ('dept_name','dept_Email','dept_password')
        widgets = {'dept_password': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

here is update_dept.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2 class="fw-bold">Edit Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" Required name="name" value="{{ prod.dept_name }}" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" Required name="price" value="{{ prod.dept_Email }}" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `dept_name` is not passed in the request, hence `prod.dept_name = request.POST.get('dept_name')` sets the name to `None`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so, why it is setting none because in the database it has values for dept_name. how can I fix it?

Comment: because you say to change it to the value provided by `request.POST.get('dept_name')`.

Comment: yes  and I am changing its value, I am not giving it null value

Comment: What do you see if you `print(request.POST.get('dept_name'))`? Since there is no item in the POST request with that name, it returns `None`, and thus will assign `None` (and thus `NULL` to the `dept_name` of the department you are editing.

Comment: yeah! It is giving me None. what i am missing?

Comment: I add my HTML file also. please tell me where I am wrong? I am a beginner in django. I checked naming is correct.

Comment: It should be `name="dept_name"` instead of `name="name"` and `name="dept_Email" instead of `name="price"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML form uses the wrong names, and therefore `request.POST` does not contain any entries like `dept_name` and `dept_Email`. You should specify `name="dept_name"` instead of <s>`name="name"`</s> and `name="dept_Email"` instead of <s>`name="price"`</s>:

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" Required name="dept_name" value="{{ prod.dept_name }}" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" Required name="dept_Email" value="{{ prod.dept_Email }}" class="form-control">
</div>
```

That being said, I would strongly advise that you use a `ModelForm`, you can make a second `ModelForm` for the department where you leave out the `dept_password`.

You can see the [*Rendering fields manually* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) that shows how you can render you Django form with custom HTML.